# Install ibm db 2 ext on PHP Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, db2

When I try to connect to a IBM DB 2 database, I get an error `Call to undefined function db2_connect()` 
I think the library php_ibm_db2 is not established

My php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

..

;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=php_pdo_ibm.dll
;extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll
extension=php_ibm_db2
```

The lib in path xampp/php/ext

php info not showed this lib in list 
Any ideas ?

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ibm_db2' (tried: C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_ibm_db2  in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Insufficient information. EDIT your question to add exact version+bitness and edition of Microsoft Windows,  the version/bitness of PHP,  the version of the ibm_db that you installed. Also verify if you Db2 client is properly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears it is necessary before installation in `phpinfo()`

1. thread safe \ not thread safe (NTS \ TS)
2. x64 - x86 version

After that  download here lib [php_ibm_db2 dll](https://github.com/ibmdb/php_ibm_db2)

Answer (score 0):

There is answer from another stackoverflow post:

[DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php) is an extension and must be installed separately before its functions are made available.

http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php

Comment: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ibm_db2' (tried: C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_ibm_db2 in Unknown on line 0